# how do i lookup an operator value in html, set it as a var and use it in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a span which reads 1+2= :

```
<span id="num1">1</span> <span id="op">+</span> <span id="num2">2</span> =
```

i have a javascript function:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var num1 = parseInt($("#num1").text());
      var op = $("#op").text();
      var num2 = parseInt($("#num2").text());
      console.log(num1 + op + num2);          //doesnt work

    });
```

this is purely for experimental reasons, but how would i go about adding 1+2 using the operator listed in my html? can i set an operator to a var and use it somehow?

my thought was to do  `console.log(num1 + op + num2);` but that doesnt do anything

Comment: you need to use eval() i.e. eval(num1 + op + num2);

Comment: well done, thank you!

Comment: Do not use `eval()`. [**`eval()` is evil!**](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not use `eval()` as it is [evil](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/).** Kindly try to mix and match the operators.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num1 = parseInt($("#num1").text());
  var num2 = parseInt($("#num2").text());
  var op = $("#op").text();
  switch (op) {
    case "+":
      console.log(num1 + num2);
      break;
    case "-":
      console.log(num1 - num2);
      break;
    case "/":
      console.log(num1 / num2);
      break;
    case "*":
      console.log(num1 * num2);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is also great because you could use something like ^ to map to Math.pow or interpret x like *.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use `eval`, which I strictly do NOT recommend  (there's a lot of reasons, just google it), you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var num1 = parseInt($("#num1").text()),
      num2 = parseInt($("#num2").text()),
      op =   $("#op").text(),
      result;

  switch(op) {
    case '+': result = num1 + num2; break;
    case '-': result = num1 - num2; break;
    case '*': result = num1 * num2; break;
    case '/': result = num1 / num2; break;
    default: /** do something else */ break;
  }

  console.log(result);

});
```